# Unable to Get Fitness Recording Client From Google Fit (Subscription)

Tags: java, android, api, google-fit

I'm working on an app that uses the android Google Fit API to record and retrieve data. I've read the documentation and so I'm trying to establish a subscription using Fitness.getRecordingClient. When you do this there are two main methods (listeners) one is onSuccess and the other is on onFailure. I ran the app in debug mode and it never enters into onSuccess or onFailure. it doesn't give me any errors. so it is kind of difficult for me to find out what's going on. If someone has experience with google fit api using android I appreciate. thanks 
google fit docs https://developers.google.com/fit/android/record
here's the StatsFragment code

```
public class StatsFragment extends Fragment  {
    private static final int GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 20;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "STATS";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stats, container, false);

        //declaring the fitnessOption client and type of data to be access
        FitnessOptions fitnessOptions = FitnessOptions.builder()
                .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .addDataType(DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                .build();

        //checking for user permisssion
        if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()), fitnessOptions)) {
            GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
                    this, // your activity
                    GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                    GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()),
                    fitnessOptions);
        } else {
            Fitness.getRecordingClient(getActivity(), GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity()))
                    .listSubscriptions(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<Subscription>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<Subscription> subscriptions) {
                            for (Subscription sc : subscriptions) {
                                DataType dt = sc.getDataType();
                                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Active subscription for data type: " + dt.getName());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this?